# Deploying nodeJS app using express & EJS to Heroku gives internal server error with console log: "Refused to load the image

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ejs

The full console log is "Refused to load the image 'https://secure-journey-68854.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

The application works perfectly fine when locally hosted. Some code from my server which must be related:

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static('public'));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
res.render("index");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your html/ejs file head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
   img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
   style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```